# Disable Button Permanently in android

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have three button in my activity when I click any of two both will get disable but when I went back to my activity they won't restore the previous state.I have tried to achieve this using shared preference but Couldn't hold button state .Can anyone tell me about the mistake that I'm doing in  shared preference.
Here I'm sharing my code with you.

**on create method**

```
spStateButton= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Button_State", 0);
    spEditor = spStateButton.edit();
```

**In Activity**

```
public void setButtonState(boolean enabled) {
    spEditor.putBoolean("btn_state", enabled);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public boolean getButtonState(){
    return spStateButton.getBoolean("btn_state", true);
}
```

**button place in my activity**

```
holder.btn_Fwd.setEnabled(getButtonState());
setButtonState(false);
holder.btn_Rec.setEnabled(getButtonState());
setButtonState(false);
```

Comment: Using SharedPreference to save view state is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You used method setButtonState(boolean enabled) for saving value to shared preference and you always call that method with parameter as false. So in shared preference the key "btn_state" having value always false.

So if you want to enable button for next time activity starts, call something like
setButtonState(true);

You can also use Singleton class to save a status value across app. Create class as below

```
public class SingleTon {

private static final SingleTon instance = new SingleTon();
private Boolean buttonState = true //initially visible

private SingleTon(){}

public static Boolean getButtonState(){
    return buttonState;
}

 public void setButtonState(Boolean buttonState){
    return instance;
    }

  public SingleTon getInstance(){
        return instance;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but I want to disable button through out my application

Comment: Since shared preference is available across entire application, what is the problem?

Comment: but I couldn't achieve it by this.

Comment: I myself don't know why button state changes when I exit and re enter to my activity.though,I have coded right.

Comment: thats because you are always saving button state as false - setButtonState(false)..thats why your button is always disabled

Comment: dude itsn't disabled always that's what problem is.I want it to disable

Comment: May you can use Singleton class to save status of button across app

Comment: can you please help me with Singleton class fro disable button

Comment: Added singleton class ..Use instance of that class to save value(buttonState) across app. Call function getInstance() to get instance of Singleton class